# Web Form Only Accepts Mouse Input - Requires Users to Enter PIN thru Virtual Keyboard

Tags: javascript, web, web-applications

I recently started working with a new piece of volunteer management software called Volgistics.

They include a module that allows volunteers to sign in and out for their shifts by accessing their account on a touch screen monitor.
The volunteers enter a unique PIN and click the continue button to get in. This is obviously really inconvenient if you have any appreciable amount of volunteers.

I currently have created a set of barcodes, and QR codes that contain the volunteers PIN numbers. The web app will accept the numbers being entered into the text field, but when you click continue, it says the pin is invalid. When I delete the text entered from the barcode scan, and enter the same number by pressing the buttons, it accepts the PIN.

I've already been told that the system is not set up to accept input from anything accept a mouse. But since the numbers are being inputted into the text field - I am skeptical that this is the case.
Can anyone help me figure out why this is happening, and a work around to fix it?

I've used several apps on my iPhone that scan the barcode into a web form as the 'scanner' as we will likely be using a tablet for sign in prior to moving to a more advance system.

They have told me that there are no specific security features that reject numbers based on their input method, though the system is not set up to be used with any other form of input device.

[Here is an example](https://sample.volgistics.com/ex/touch.dll/?FROM=1&PW=306350773) VicTouch module with useable PINs.

Comment: Some PIN entry forms encode the pins during entry, so the value entered in the form is not the raw PIN codes, or actually take their input from a hidden field.  You may want to simulate clicks using the `click()` event trigger on the buttons to make it work all the way.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I'm sorry, but I'm so green to programming.

I understand the principal, like simulating the clicks and seeing what the raw click represents, but how would I go about doing that?